# Something is overwriting the ZONE setting in CentOS 7 network configuration files

Tags: centos, network-interface, networkmanager, firewalld

I have multi-homed CentOS 7 servers, and I configure their NICs by editing the ifcfg-* files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` (automatically with Ansible). In particular, that's where I specify the *firewalld* zone for each NIC, using the `ZONE=` directive. I haven't had this problem with CentOS 7.4, and now I experience it on a test server with CentOS 7.6, and (for now) with no connection on the NIC for one of the zones.

It seems as if something is overwriting my settings, changing the custom zone values I specify to `ZONE=public` or just empty `ZONE=`. What can that be, and how can I stop it from doing so?

Comment: ZONE= is the firewalld zone that your firewall daemon uses for the interface.  Is firewalld changing it?  For example, running `firewall-cmd --permanent --change-zone=eth0 --zone=public`

Comment: Can it edit the files in network scripts? I'm not sending any command that would likely do that AFAIK, but that's definitely a possible explanation.